# Limit the number of pages displayed in bootstrap 3 pagination

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, twitter-bootstrap, pagination

I have various web pages on my website which are using bootstraps (bootstrap 3) pagination but I need to know how to limit the number of pages displayed in it (e.g. display pages 1 to 10 only).

If you then select page 2, page 11 would b displayed and so on.

How do you do this?

I know it will probably be JavaScript/jQuery but any help is appreciated. and if it can be done without having to use JavaScript/jQuery, then all the better.

Below is a screenshot of my pagination.

[image: Current pagination]

As you can see there are 12 pages displayed, I would like pages 11 & 12 to be hidden until page 2 or the next page is selected then pages 11 would be displayed and pages one would be hidden, so on and so on.

Comment: So you want a maximum of 10 pagenumbers displayed?

Comment: If you select 2, 1 will not be shown?

Comment: JNF & A1rPun - Yes this is correct

Answer (score 20, accepted):

There is a jquery plugin to work with bootstrap, that solves this problem:
http://josecebe.github.io/twbs-pagination/
Have a look at the "visible pages option" section.

You can find more/other solutions with google and `bootstrap 3 pagination many pages`.

Comment: This solution is perfect! Thanks for this tip.

Comment: Updated the link.

Answer (score 6):

Assuming your page is rendered server side (PHP, Ruby, Java etc) you're likely going to want to render the pagination properly on the server side.

I solved this problem not so long ago in PHP, I had a function which was called for every page number which decided whether that number should be rendered (or something else).

It went something like this

```
if the page number is < 3, render the page number
if the page number is within +-2 of the current page, render the page number
if the page number is > the total number of pages -3 render the page number
if the last page number wasn't rendered and dots haven't already been rendered render dots '...' to indicate a gap

else do nothing
```

I hope this points you in the right kind of direction

Answer (score 6):

This question was asked long ago, but it came up while I was looking for an answer.

Specifying `max-size='X'` worked for me. The bootstrap pagination tag would look like:

```
<pagination class="pagination-sm" total-items="1000" items-per-page="10" max-size="10">
</pagination>
```

Hope this helps someone.

Answer (score 1):

You can try `reviews.maxPages` as shown below:

```
<pagination 
    total-items="reviews.count"
    ng-model="reviews.pageNo"
    max-size="reviews.maxPages"
    boundary-links="true"
    rotate="false"
    num-pages="reviews.noPages"
    ng-change="changePageTo(reviews.pageNo)"></pagination>
```

Comment: Where does `pagination` tag come from?